# Sorting Array of Structure by Mutiple Criteria with Bubble Sort in C

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I'm trying to implement a bubble sort for an array of struct with multiple sorting criteria.

Basically, the program compute how many follower a user has and also how many other users this user is following.

The result should be sorted by the following criteria:

1. Rank the user by number of followers from highest to lowest.
2. If the number of followers is equal, rank be the number of follow from highest to lowest.
3. If criteria 1 and 2 has the same number, sort the user "index" from lowest to highest (like in the case of user 0 and 3).

I have managed to come up with the sort but it only sort by 1 property, which showing in the code, it is sorting by number of follower only. I'm not really sure with is the next step from here.

Also, I'm trying to make the sort a separate function out side of the main(), but it needs access to u[i].node, u[i].nFollower, and u[i].nFollow. And I don't know what is the correct way to do it. Could you please show the the correct syntax to do it, since I'm very new to C.

Thank you very much!

Input:

```
Enter the number of users: 6
Enter a user (follower): 0
Enter a user (followed by 0): 1
Enter a user (follower): 1
Enter a user (followed by 1): 5
Enter a user (follower): 3
Enter a user (followed by 3): 5
Enter a user (follower): 5
Enter a user (followed by 5): 0
Enter a user (follower): 2
Enter a user (followed by 5): 5
Enter a user (follower): 1
Enter a user (followed by 5): 3
Enter a user (follower): #
Done.
```

Output without sorting

```
5 has 3 followers(s) and follows 1 user(s).
0 has 1 followers(s) and follows 1 user(s).
3 has 1 followers(s) and follows 1 user(s).
1 has 1 followers(s) and follows 2 user(s).
4 has 0 followers(s) and follows 0 user(s).
2 has 0 followers(s) and follows 1 user(s).
```

Desired output:

```
5 has 3 followers(s) and follows 1 user(s).
1 has 1 followers(s) and follows 2 user(s).
0 has 1 followers(s) and follows 1 user(s).
3 has 1 followers(s) and follows 1 user(s).
2 has 0 followers(s) and follows 1 user(s).
4 has 0 followers(s) and follows 0 user(s).
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "WGraph.h"

typedef struct User {
    int node;
    int nFollower;
    int nFollow;
} User;

int main (void) {
    Edge e = {0, 0, 1};
    int nUsers;

    printf("Enter the number of users: ");
    scanf("%d", &nUsers);
    
    Graph g = newGraph(nUsers);

    printf("Enter a user (follower): ");
    while (scanf("%d", &e.v) == 1) {
        printf("Enter a user (followed by 0): ");
        scanf("%d", &e.w);
        insertEdge(g, e);
        printf("Enter a user (follower): ");
    }
    printf("Done.\n");

    //showGraph(g);


    int nV = numOfVertices(g);
    int countFollower;
    int countFollow;
    User u[nV];
    printf("Ranking by follower base:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < nV; i++) {
        countFollow = 0;
        countFollower = 0;
        u[i].node = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < nV; j++) {
            if (adjacent(g, j, i) != 0) {
                countFollower++;
            }

            if (adjacent(g, i, j) != 0) {
                countFollow++;
            }
        }
        u[i].nFollower = countFollower;
        u[i].nFollow = countFollow;
    }
    
    //Sort and update array of struct
    int temp1;
    int temp2;
    int temp3;
    for (int i = 0; i < nV; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nV; j++) {
            if (u[i].nFollower > u[j].nFollower) {
                temp1 = u[j].nFollow;
                temp2 = u[j].nFollower;
                temp3 = u[j].node;
                u[j].nFollow = u[i].nFollow;
                u[i].nFollow = temp1;
                u[j].nFollower = u[i].nFollower;
                u[i].nFollower = temp2;
                u[j].node = u[i].node;
                u[i].node = temp3;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nV; i++) {
        printf("%d has %d followers(s) and follows %d user(s).\n", u[i].node, u[i].nFollower, u[i].nFollow);
    }

    //freeGraph(g);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why move the whole structure when you can move just the pointers to them? And, is `bubble-sort` mandatory? Why not use standard library `qsort()`?

Comment: Your swap is grotesque.  Use `if (u[i].nFollower > u[j].nFollower) { User t = u[i]; u[i] = u[j]; u[j] = t; }` — making use of structure assignment.

Comment: The way the standard C library `qsort()` function handles arbitrary comparisons is by having the programmer pass a pointer-to-function as a comparator which is invoked to compare two elements of the array.  The return value from the comparator is positive, negative, or zero (for 'first argument after second', 'first argument before second', 'arguments are equal').  You won't know how to pass pointers to functions yet, but you could still write a comparator function that takes two `const User *` arguments.  You can pass arrays to functions — which is another of your questions.

Comment: I did not know about qsort() before, but by the look of it, it could be a good solution for this issue. I will keep reading to see if I can use it...Thanks a lot for the suggestion guys!

Comment: This is **not** bubblesort. It isn't even conservative...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check for the condition while sorting in bubble sort

```
for (int i = 0; i < nV; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < nV; j++) {
                        if ((u[i].nFollower > u[j].nFollower) || \
                                        (u[i].nFollower == u[j].nFollower && u[i].Follow > u[j].Follow) || \ 
                                        (u[i].nFollower == u[j].nFollower && u[i].Follow == u[j].Follow && i < j)) {
                                temp1 = u[j].nFollow;
                                temp2 = u[j].nFollower;
                                temp3 = u[j].node;
                                u[j].nFollow = u[i].nFollow;
                                u[i].nFollow = temp1;
                                u[j].nFollower = u[i].nFollower;
                                u[i].nFollower = temp2;
                                u[j].node = u[i].node;
                                u[i].node = temp3;
                        }
                }
        }
```

here we are iterating n-1 time and each time we iterate we skip the elements which are in proper order. Instead of using temperory variable I am using `xor` operator to swap elements.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < nV-1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j+1 <= nv-1-i; j++) {
                        if ((u[j].nFollower > u[j+1].nFollower) || \
                                        (u[j].nFollower == u[j+1].nFollower && u[j].Follow > u[j+1].Follow)) {

                                u[j].nFollow ^= u[j+1].nFollow;
                                u[j+1].nFollow ^= u[j].nFollow;
                                u[j].nFollow ^= u[j+1].nFollow;

                                u[j].nFollower ^= u[j+1].nFollower;
                                u[j+1].nFollower ^= u[j].nFollower;
                                u[j].nFollower ^= u[j+1].nFollower;

                                u[j].node ^= u[j+1].node;
                                u[j+1].node ^= u[j].node;
                                u[j].node ^= u[j+1].node;
                        }
                }
        }
```

Comment: That condition line should be split into at least 3 lines.  And I think the last `>` should be `==`.

Comment: You don't need the backslash at the end of the lines — the compiler ignores white space for the most part.  Your third line of the condition should read: `(u[i].nFollower == u[j].nFollower && u[i].Follow == u[j].Follow && i < j)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solves the problem. Therefore I ahve marked it as accepted answer. However, after thinking about it, I think bubble sort is not a very good implementation so I may try to use qsort...

Comment: @JonathanLeffer thanks for pointing out the bug for the last condition in if statement I have fixed it.